# Is it possible to get pod metrics from prometheus without RBAC?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have a Kubernetes namespace with limited privileges which excludes the creation of `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`.
I want to monitor the resource consumption and pod-related metrics on the namespace level.

E.g., pod health and status, new pod creation, pod restarts, etc.

Although I can create an application-level metrics endpoint for custom metrics by exposing `/metrics` and adding the annotation `prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'`.

But is there a way to get `resource consumption and pod-related metrics` on the namespace level without `Cluster Role` and `ClusterRoleBinding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get namespace level entities from kube-state-metrics.

1. Pull the helm chart for kube-state-metrics:
   https://bitnami.com/stack/kube-state-metrics/helm
2. Edit the values.yaml file and make the following changes:

   ```
          rbac:
              create: false
              useClusterRole: false
            collectors:
              - configmaps
              - cronjobs
              - daemonsets
              - deployments
              - endpoints
              - horizontalpodautoscalers
              - ingresses
              - jobs
              - limitranges
              - networkpolicies
              - poddisruptionbudgets
              - pods
              - replicasets
              - resourcequotas
              - services
              - statefulsets
            namespace: <current-namespace>
   ```
3. In the prometheus ConfigMap, add a job with the following configurations:

   ```
    - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
        scrape_interval: 1s
        scrape_timeout: 500ms
        static_configs:
             - targets: ['{{ .Values.kube_state_metrics.service.name }}:8080']
   ```
4. Create a role binding:

   ```
        apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
        kind: RoleBinding
        metadata:
          name: kube-state-metrics
          namespace: <current-namespace>
        roleRef:
          apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
          kind: ClusterRole
          name: view
        subjects:
          - kind: ServiceAccount
            name: kube-state-metrics
        namespace: <current-namespace>
   ```